# Prevent user directly accessing files inside specific folder using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to prevent users from directly accessing specific folder files by hitting URLs in browsers like https://sampledomain.com/folder/1.jpg.

For that I implemented this code in .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|txt|zip|rar|)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

But It applied to all the directories available inside my server. I want to prevent user from directly accessing specific directory files.

Can anyone please help with the same?

Comment: Put that htaccess inside the folder you want to protect. Another, easier and more robust solution would be to put the folder outside the  webserver's document root

Comment: @M.Eriksson - I think the OP wants certain files to be accessible.  Rajat - My suggestion would be to separate them into separate folders and follow M.Erriksson's advice